# $S$ is a linear operator over $V$ with such that $S^n =0$ but $S^{(n-1)} \ne 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V a vector space over a field $K$ with dimension n and let $ \beta= \{v_1,...,v_n \}\ $  is a basis of $V$ and $T(v_i) = v_{i+1}$ and $T(v_n)=0$.

Prove that if $S$ is a linear operator over $V$  with such that $S^n =0$ but $S^{(n-1)} \ne 0$. Then there exist a basis $\beta ´$ of $V$ such that the matrix of $S$ with respect to $\beta ´$ is the matrix of representation with basis $\beta$ in $T(v_i) = v_{i+1}$ and $T(v_n)=0$

How can i prove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a vector $\xi \in V$ with $S^{n-1}\xi \neq 0$ and show that $(\xi, S^1 \xi, \dots, S^{n-1}\xi)$ is a basis of $V$ that achieves what you want.